# Static variable in Spring Data Neo4j with advanced mapping is null

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

In the code there is a static variable used to initialize the variable classID for the Node Entity,

```
@NodeEntity
public class Person{
    @GraphId
    Long id;
    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private Integer personID;
    private static int nextID = 0;

public Person(){
this.personID=nextID++;
} }
```

On executing, I get a NPE for nextID variable. How do we set a static variable in aspectj mapping for SDN.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the concrete exception?

Comment: DEBUG o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Setting JTA transaction rollback-only
DEBUG o.s.t.jta.JtaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.DetachedEntityState.getValueFromEntity(DetachedEntityState.java:262)
 at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.DetachedEntityState.getValue(DetachedEntityState.java:88)
 at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.DetachedEntityState.getValue(DetachedEntityState.java:112)
 at demo.Person.nextID_aroundBody3$advice(Person.java:256)

Comment: Can none of the class variables be static? What should we do if we want static variables?

Answer (score 1):

1. Why do you need an extra id `personID`, while you already have `@GraphId id`? Using `@GraphId` is meant for generating unique node id, so I don't see a point in using 2 unique ids for 1 entity/node.
2. Using `static int nextID` for generating id is bad design. You'll get duplicates in database whenever you'll restart your application (nextID will be set to 0).

Comment: 1.It is advised not to refer to the @GraphID value in the code and also I need to pass the value of the extra id to other node entities.  2.As per the requirement,we have to clean the database for every user session.But will surely look into for cases for system failure.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Can you provide link to document which is saying that @GraphId value shouldn't be used in the code?

Comment: But I have some other static variables besides for the ID generation. All throw NPE when I use advanced mapping.Do you have any solution for those.Thanks